# Recommended way to uninstall Istio?

Tags: kubernetes, helm, istio, kubernetes-helm, upgrade

I installed Istio with `istioctl` and our cluster has multiple Istio control planes. So as part of upgrading to a new Istio version, I want to delete the older version. What is the recommended approach?

1. `istioctl x uninstall -f manifest`
2. `helm uninstall` (in my case this doesn't work as I'm not installing with `helm`)

Any other approaches?

Comment: BTW: `istioctl uninstall --help`, we use revisions thus we uninstall via `istioctl uninstall --revision 1.2.3`.